# Tensorflow: BasicLSTM and dynamicRNN - Value error when trying to reuse the model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to reuse the trained model(LSTM with RNN) for the different data set, however
I am experiencing some Valueerror when I use the codes below:

```
ValueError: Variable LSTM/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable()
```

**Can anyone please advise me on this? Thank you!**

**In the main file, the codes are below:**

```
# build a LSTM network
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)

with tf.variable_scope("LSTM") as vs:
outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
Y_pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], output_dim, activation_fn=None)


#To reuse Variables
lstm_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,   scope=vs.name)

#Initialize the LSTM variables.
tf.initialize_variables(lstm_variables)

with tf.Session() as sess:
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

##### Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

**In another file, I want to reuse the trained model,**

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model.ckpt.meta")
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh,reuse=True)

with tf.variable_scope("LSTM", reuse=True) as vs:
outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
Y_pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], output_dim, activation_fn=None)
lstm_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=vs.name)
tf.initialize_variables(lstm_variables)
```

Comment: Hi vijay, thank you for answering the question. Unfortunately, I encountered another error using the code. 

It says **KeyError: "The name 'Y_pred:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Y_pred', does not exist in the graph."**

'Y_pred' is just a fully connected layer. Can you please advise me on this?

Comment: Did you name your tensor y_pred to "Y_pred" ? You can use `y_pred = tf.identity(y_pred, name='Y_pred')` do so.

Comment: Thank you for replying! vijay I have updated the code based on your advice but it says 'NameError: name 'y_pred' is not defined' Maybe I missed something in the main file.

Comment: Check how you have named your tensor: 'y_pred' or 'Y_pred'. And when you are using get_tensor_by_name make sure u append ':0'. Share your code snippet if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you, Vijay. I have used 'Y_pred' for it.

I think I have problems when I make tensors for cell, outputs, _states, Y_pred. Can you please give me an example for these variables?

Comment: To make the cell as a tensor, do I need to make it as a placeholder first to use 'name'? 
For example, 

   cell = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='cell')
    
   cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
    num_units=hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)

Comment: Thank you for replying, vijay. I tried the code above but it still has error.

Comment: TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x7ff73ddeb290>

Comment: I like your solution using 'import meta graph' function. However, in order to reuse the lstm + dynamic RNN, can you please advise me which variables should be a tensor with 'name' using tf.identity()?

Comment: For each variable go and check the tensorflow website. If the function has 'name=' you can set it directly. If it doesnt check whether it returns a tensor. If it returns a tensor then use tf.Identity(). Here in above `cell`, it returns a list (c_state and m_state) of variables if `state_is_tuple` = True, it its False, it returns a single concated tensor.

Comment: Thank you so much, vijay I'll try this to solve the problem. Thank you so much for putting your effort on this!